# use of model data in ajax success

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'LeadPipes/LeadCounts',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data)

        }
    });
});
```

I am using the ajax call above to get a model back how would i use the model object in the success function. As in I need to be able to use the data like a views model like @model.Type lets say. how could i do that with the json data in the success?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` object contains the properties passed down via the server.

You can then access them like:

```
 var name = data.Name;
 var testData = data.TestData;
```

Your `Action` could look like:

```
public JsonResult LeadCounts() 
{
   return Json(new { name = "Darren", testData = "Testing" });
}
```

Comment: well the data returns a Model containing other models actually. thats the problem. its not something i am putting into the json is there no way to do that unless i specifically set the (new{name="Darren"})

Comment: You can go deep with models. So you can use the dot accessor to go as deep as you need. See my vehicle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ttaCp/

Comment: @CoreyToolis you can certainly just call `return Json(myComplexObject);`  That was just a sample anonymous object @Darren used to explain

Answer (score 2):

In MVC3 you could do it like this:

```
public ActionResult LeadCounts()
{
    var data = new { Count = 1, Something = "Something" };

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'LeadPipes/LeadCounts',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.Count);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that I'm explicitly allowing `GET` requests (with `sonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`). It is not needed in this case as you are using `POST` request.